# JQM page is not getting refreshed when revisited

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have total four pages: Page1, Page2, Page3 and Page4. Page3 contains Select dropdown menu. Previously, when I was selecting a value from the dropdown of Page3 and move to Page4 and return back to Page3, the selected value does not get retained and the Page3 get reset to its default value. So one of the developer suggest me to use data-dom-cache="true" on Page3 and my problem was resolved. But it has created an another problem.

```
Page1 -> Page2 -> Page3 (No problem)
Page3 -> Page2 (No problem)
Page2 -> Page3 (Problem! No data was displayed except Header, Footer, 
Logos and Select dropdown box)
```

If I remove `data-dom-cache="true"` from the Page3 then data get displayed but the selected value get lost when revisited from Page4.

Page3 code: http://jsbin.com/owodon/14/edit

```
//Code for triggering Page3 from Page2
$('.clsChangeLi').live("click", function () {
    var Pg3URL = $(this).attr("data-url");
    if (Pg3URL != null)
        $.mobile.changePage(Pg3URL, {
            transition: "flip",
            reloadPage: true
        });
});

//Code snippet for Page3
$('#CAL').live('pagebeforecreate', function (event) {
    var html = "";
    (AJAX request goes here and data is received in html variable)
    html = "Data returned by AJAX";
    $('#divContentCAL').append(html);
});
```

I tried each of the following after `$('#divContentCAL').append(html);` but not working:

```
$('ul').listview('refresh');
$('#divContentCAL').listview('refresh');
$.fn.listview('refresh');
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated...thanks.